# Create a new perfil inside a persons _controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, submit

I'm in rails 3.2.2
I'm trying to create a new perfil inside a persons_controller
Models symplify:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :perfil, :foreign_key=>'perfil_id'
class Perfil < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :person
```

I created ad_perfil inside persons_controller

```
def ad_perfil
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  @perfil = Perfil.new
end
```

and I supused 2 ways:
1) using f.submit

```
ad_perfil.html.erb:
  <%= @person.nombre %>
  <%= form_for(@perfil) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :nombre %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :nombre %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

this redirect me to create to perfils_controller and there I can't get @persona:

```
 def create
      @perfil = Perfil.new(params[:perfil])
      @person = Person.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
        if @perfil.save
          format.html { redirect_to @perfil, notice: 'Perfil was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @perfil, status: :created, location: @perfil }
          @person.perfil_id = @perfil.id
          @person.save
```

2) I created a new def in persons_controller:

```
def new_perf
 @perfil = Perfil.new(params[:perfil])
 @person = Person.find(params[:id])
 if @perfil.save
   @person.perfil = @perfil
   @person.update_attributes(params[:person])
   redirect_to @person
end
end
```

and I tryed change f.submit for:

```
<td><%= link_to 'New Perfil', :action => "new_perf", :id=> @person.id %></td>
```

and it created a new perfil without any field and of course don save perfil.id inside @person.perfil_id.
Is possible that I'm trying? Is there any other methods? I guess that will be more easy puting perfil.person_id instead person.perfil_id but I want access to person.perfil later.
I hope you understand me, and maybe I don't understand "submit" very well. any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Not exactly sure why you prefixed every code line with a `$`, but can you please edit your question to remove them?

Comment: Of course, Is my first question here and I thought that the page said me that it was necesary for code format ;) @meagar